# Vue-router history mode is not working when using axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router

I want to get the data from `http://localhost:5438/api/change?id=123` when visiting `http://localhost:8080/change/detail/123`, but it's not working when using history mode.

**The dev config**

```
assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
        '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5438/api/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': ''
        }
    }
},
```

**The router config**

```
{
    path: '/change/detail/:id',
    name: 'ChangeDetail',
    component: ChangeDetail
}
```

**ChangeDetail**

```
this.$axios.get('api/change?id=' + id)
    .then(response => {
        ......
    })
```

However, I find the url axios is actually calling is,

`http://localhost:8080/change/detail/api/change?id=123` instead of `http://localhost:8080/api/change?id=123`

But when I turn off the history mode, everything is fine when the url is turned to `http://localhost:8080/#/change/detail/123`.

So what's wrong? Please help me to find a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a relative path in axios (relative to the current URL **path**). Use an absolute path instead as that is literally what you have in your `proxyTable`, ie `/api/change`. **Voting to close as a typo**

Comment: @Phil Thanks, did you mean change `this.$axios.get('api/change?id=' + id)` to `this.$axios.get('/api/change?id=' + id)`? I've tried that but it's still the same result.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I very much doubt that it produces the same problem unless you've set axios to use a `baseUrl` that you haven't shown.

Comment: @Phil Ok, its now working, thank you!

Comment: @Phil you might want to move your comment to the answer section?

Comment: @RuChernChong it's really not worth it, this is just a typo

Comment: Alright then :)